# SQL need help on a request

Tags: mysql, sql

I need your help on a SQL request.  Here are my tables:

Table Events:

```
id    |    idType    |    used_by
1            1              Marc
2            1                
3            1              Henry
```

Table Types:

```
id    |    name    |    activate
1         Type 1           0
2         Type 2           1
```

As you can see, I have Type 1 inactivate, but 2 persons are using it. I would like to display records from Events that have a type activated and also display records that are used by someone even if the type is inactivated.

The SQL below only displays events that have type activated:

```
CREATE TABLE events (id int(11), idType int(11), used_by varchar(50));
INSERT INTO events VALUES (1, 1, ''), (2, 1, 'Marc'), (3, 1, 'Henry'), (4, 2, ''), (5, 2, 'Sandy');

CREATE TABLE types (id int(11), name varchar(50), activate int(1));
INSERT INTO types VALUES (1, 'Type1' , 0), (2, 'Type 2', 1);

SELECT events.id, types.name, events.used_by 
FROM events 
INNER JOIN types 
ON events.idType = types.id 
WHERE types.activate = 1
```

Here is the sqlfiddle: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a36f/1 and as a result i would like from events ids: 2, 3 , 4 ,5

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Here is my sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a36f/1 and as a result i would like from events ids: 2, 3 , 4 ,5

Comment: @Alexking2005 In future, just add small code snippets into your question directly, instead of providing external links. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: sorry, I see that I am often criticized about my questions'sformulations, i try to be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an OR condition for the used_by field:

```
SELECT events.id, types.name, events.used_by
FROM events 
    INNER JOIN types 
    ON events.idType = types.id 
WHERE types.activate = 1
    OR events.used_by != ''
```

Edited to replace events.used_by check to look for non-blank rather than not null based on updated information.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a36f/2 As you can see, it returns all ids, i only need 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: Ok, I updated this to look for non-blank rather than not null based on the characteristics of your data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a36f/8

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
SELECT events.id, types.name, events.used_by FROM events INNER JOIN types ON events.idType = types.id WHERE types.activate=1 or trim(events.used_by)<>''
```

Or

```
SELECT events.id, types.name, events.used_by FROM events INNER JOIN types ON events.idType = types.id WHERE types.activate=1 or not isnull(events.used_by)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select e.*
from evsnts e
    join types t on t.id = e.idtype
where t.Activate = 1 or 
      (e.used_by is not null and len(e.used_By) > 0)
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a36f/4 it seems bood, thanks. I managed to do the same thing with a union request, but i think yours is better, because union use high ressource.

Answer (score 0):

correct me if I understood wrong, you want to display all records from events table, which are used by someone, irrespective of type activated or deactivated,

for this you can simplu qyery on event table

Select * from events where used_by is not null and used_by!=''

Comment: thanks for your answer, no because i want events (even if these are empty in used_by) for which idType is activated.